# Firefox: getting access to the list of tabs/windows to restore on startup

Tags: firefox, data-recovery, browser-tabs

Sometimes Firefox fails to restore the previously open tabs/windows.

This might be happening when some of the URLs to be opened are no longer reachable (e.g. behind a VPN) or after the underlying OS (Windows) has been forcibly restarted (e.g. to complete an automated patch installation).

Anyway, after restarting, can this list of URLs be recovered somehow? Say for example, I was daft enough to have clicked on "start new session". Can I still get access to the old list of open URLs?

There is the browser history of course, but it contains a lot of stuff - the URLs that were open when Firefox last exited are not obvious. It would be neat if they were marked in some way - tagged for example.

Comment: For current Firefox versions (2022), see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111805/111036)

Answer (score 0):

If you said "start new session", the old list of tabs are probably deleted. Since FF 3.5, if the browser crashes, it doesn't just bring up a dialog box if you want to restore your session, but it opens a tab that lists the open tabs of the crashed session, where you can select which tabs you want to restore. If you close down FF properly, though, it will restore the last session without asking if you clicked on "save session" when you exited last time.

Comment: The old list of tabs is NOT deleted right away. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/126749/firefox-getting-access-to-the-list-of-tabs-windows-to-restore-on-startup#506140).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like more control over how firefox handles sessions, you should take a look at [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2324/) It's probably the best addon of it's kind.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: ["In Firefox, I accidentally clicked “Start New Session” after a crash. How can I get all my tabs back?"](https://superuser.com/questions/531810/in-firefox-i-accidentally-clicked-start-new-session-after-a-crash-how-can-i)

Comment: that topic has been deleted (why?).

Comment: @foo: It was an off-topic Stack Overflow question. It has been moved to Super User because it didn't fit well with Stack Overflow's mission statement. I have updated the link.