# In Firefox, I accidentally clicked "Start New Session" after a crash. How can I get all my tabs back?

Tags: firefox, session-restore

[user1264624](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264624/user1264624) asks [on another website:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952032/in-firefox-i-accidentally-clicked-start-new-session-after-a-crash-how-can-i)

> After a Firefox crash, I accidentally clicked "Start New Session" instead of "Restore". Unfortunately there is no way to get back to the previous session as the other possibilities to restore are deactivated to click them, looks like the sessions is completely lost.
>
> Is there a way to get it restored?
>
> I did try `about:sessionrestore`, but no luck, 
>   `about:home` but there's no session restore available, from History menu it's inactive to select.
>
> Please do suggest any possibilities to restore the session (Note, I did not close the Firefox window nor I restarted the system once I lost the session but using a new session in the same window)

Comment: This question is related to, but [not quite an exact duplicate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), of ["Where does Firefox store the opened windows/tabs/urls for Session Restore after a crash?"](http://superuser.com/questions/134256/where-does-firefox-store-the-opened-windows-tabs-urls-for-session-restore-after).  I wonder if you could please reopen this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Firefox 3 stores its session data in a JavaScript file located in the [user profile folder](http://www.openmediaboston.org/node/905). To restore an accidentally discarded session, simply:
>
> 1. Quit Firefox.
> 2. Replace the current JavaScript file with the [backed-up version](http://www.openmediaboston.org/node/905).
> 3. Restart Firefox.

—Jesse Kirdahy-Scalia (13 September 2009). ["Restore a Lost or Discarded Firefox Session in Three Quick Steps"](http://www.openmediaboston.org/node/905). *Open Media Boston*. Media Working Group, Inc.

Comment: Seems, that something has changed for newer Firefox versions.

Answer (score 2):

kudos to jasonspiro's answer. You might also want to install [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) if you don't want the hassle of recovering tabs from a crash.